# Unable to create an opportunity with primary campaign source - insufficient access rights on cross reference id

Tags: insufficient-privileges

Unable to create an opportunity with a primary campaign source, error stating insufficient privileges.

But without selecting a primary campaign source and creating an opportunity can successfully create a record and a primary campaign source can be added later while editing the record.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to add the same primary campaign after creating an Opp and later updating? Coz here there could be couple of possibilities, probably you might have added a lookup filter(if so later you create even then you wouldn't be able to add the same primary campaign) Or it would be an issue of "no access" for that record.

Comment: Finally I managed to solve it in the following way. In the flow (in before insert) I save the Id of the campaign in a text field, and after creating the record, in another flow (in after insert) I add the value of the text field with the Id, in the field CampaignId.

I don't have any filter on the CampaignId field.